# Time Series w/ multiple variables, groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a time series in ggplot for certain export markets, for example-sake, Japan. I want to focus on a few different export items (e.g. pork, beef, wheat,etc.) by exporter (e.g. US, EU, Australia, etc.). I'd like to be able to set up the data so that I can use facet_wrap to show a graph for each of those goods in one image (representing the Japanese market), that has all relevant exporters. I've been trying to use geom_line but I have no idea how to arrange the data so that I can use facet_wrap, ggplot, etc.

Comment: Adam please share a reproducible example with `dput`, use the following code: `dput(head(df))` and copy and paste the output from the console.

Answer (score 0):

You need two columns that specify the exporter and country, in long format (so each row is a unique combination of product, exporter, country and date). A reproducible example of this is shown below.

Then, the key plot element is using facet_grid(exporter~product).

```
export_data.df <- data.frame(
  value = runif(36),
  Date =  rep(c(rep(as.Date("1999/1/1"),3),
                rep(as.Date("1999/1/2"),3),
                rep(as.Date("1999/1/3"),3),
                rep(as.Date("1999/1/4"),3)),3),
  exporter = rep(rep(c("Japan","USA","NZ"),3),4),
  product = rep(c(rep("Pork",3),rep("Beef",3),rep("Chicken",3)),4)
)

ggplot(export_data.df) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Date,y = value)) +
  facet_grid(exporter~product)
```

[Output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLPxG.png)